# How to calculate all pixels on the circumference of an ellipse?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am drawing an ellipse in a "canvas" element with the following lines of code:

```
            let centerX = 250, centerY = 250;
            let widthEllipse = 75;
            let heightEllipse = 50;

            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.ellipse(centerX, centerY, heightEllipse, widthEllipse, Math.PI / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.stroke();
```

As a result, I get this drawing:
[image]

How can I calculate all the pixels on the circumference of an ellipse?
For example, to make such calculations for a circle, I used the following formulas:
[image]

```
for (let y = 0; y < r*2; y++) {
    P1=(x0-sqrt(r^2-(y-y0)^2), y);
    P2=(x0+sqrt(r^2-(y-y0)^2), y;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even work for a circle. Near the top and bottom, there are typically many pixels on the same row. Also notice that the ellipse you showed is antialiased, so the definition of pixels that are "on" the circumference is fuzzy.

Comment: @Thomas, You're right, but I used this to connect P1 and P2 and got a crosshatched drawing.

Comment: That's the area, not the circumference then. You'll need to edit your question to clarify which pixels you want exactly.

Comment: I need all the pixels around the circumference of an ellipse. Perhaps the circle example is not very suitable, I just don’t understand how I can solve my problem

Comment: Pixels are discrete squares. The circumference of an ellipse is an infinitisimally thin curve. So do you want all pixels that intersect the circumference? Or all pixels that a non-antialised ellipse renderer would draw? These two are different; the first will have "staircases" whereas the second will have pixels that only touch on the corners. Also please clarify how your ellipse is represented in code, because there are many different possible parameterizations.

Answer (score 0):

### Scan lines. Axis Aligned ellipse

The first example is simple and only handles axis aligned ellipses.

Call is `scanEllipse(x, y, xRadius, yRadius);`

```js
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
scanEllipse(102, 64, 100, 30);
scanEllipse(256, 64, 40, 60);
function scanEllipse(x, y, h, v) {
    const hSqr = h * h;
    const scale = h / v;
    var i = -v;
    while (i <= v) {
        var ii = i * scale;
        var p1 = (hSqr - ii * ii) ** 0.5;
        ctx.fillStyle = i % 2 ? "#F00" : "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(x - p1, y + i, p1 * 2, 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="300" height="128"></canvas>
```

### Scan lines. Rotated ellipse

This gets messy. To make sure it covers as many cases as possible I animated the function. I could not see any glitches but there may be some cases (very big ellipse or ellipses with very large eccentricity) where the floating point error may cause artifacts.

Call is `scanEllipse(x, y, xRadius, yRadius, ang);`  `ang` is in radians.

```js
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
const quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find quadratic roots
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) { return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : []  }
    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);
    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }
    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}
function drawHLine(x, y, w) {
    ctx.fillStyle = y % 2 ? "#F00" : "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, 1);   
}
function scanEllipse(x, y, h, v, a) {
    const C = Math.cos(a), C2 = C * C;        
    const S = Math.sin(a), S2 = S * S;
    const v2 = v * v, h2 = h * h;
    const A = v2 * C2 + h2 * S2;
    var i = 0, a, b, scan = true;
    function atY(y) {
        const B = 2 * y * C * S * (v2 - h2);
        const c = y * y *(v2 * S2 + h2 * C2 )- h2 * v2;
        return quadRoots(A, B, c);
    }
    while (scan) {
        [a, b] = atY(i);
        if (a !== undefined && b !== undefined) {
            drawHLine(x + a, y + i, b - a);
            if (i > 0) {
                [a, b] = atY(-i);
                drawHLine(x + a, y - i, b - a);
            }
        } else { scan = false; }
        i++;
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    const h = Math.sin(time * 0.001) * 45 + 50;
    const v = Math.sin(time * 0.00333) * 35 + 40;
    scanEllipse(100, 100, h, v, time * 0.00077);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

### Scan lines. Rotated ellipse edge only

Addresses just the outside pixels. (to fit the rules of good pixel art line work).

The function uses the same method as above by uses each previous row to workout which pixels are edge pixels.

There is plenty of room for optimization and the animation is slowed just a little to let use see the pixels.

Not that this version calculates the left and right edge using the center of each pixel row (eg y + 0.5). Using the top or bottom of the row makes for a lesser quality ellipse IMHO.

Call is `scanEllipse(x, y, xRadius, yRadius, ang);`  `ang` is in radians.

```js
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
const quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find quadratic roots
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) { return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : []  }
    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);
    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }
    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}
function drawHLine(x, y, w) {
    ctx.fillStyle = y % 2 ? "#F00" : "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, 1);   
}
function scanEllipse(x, y, h, v, a) {
    const C = Math.cos(a), C2 = C * C;        
    const S = Math.sin(a), S2 = S * S;
    const v2 = v * v, h2 = h * h;
    const A = v2 * C2 + h2 * S2;
    var i = 0, a1, b1, a2, b2, scan = true;
    var pa1, pb1, pa2, pb2; // p for previous 
    
    function atY(y) {
        const B = 2 * y * C * S * (v2 - h2);
        const c = y * y *(v2 * S2 + h2 * C2 )- h2 * v2;
        return quadRoots(A, B, c);
    }
    const max = Math.max, min = Math.min;
    const addPx = (x, y) => ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    const addEdgeLine = (x1, x2, y) => {
        [x1, x2] = [min(x1, x2) | 0, max(x1, x2) | 0];
        if (x1 == x2) { addPx(x1++, y); }        
        while (x1 < x2) {addPx(x1++, y);}
    }
    while (scan) {
        [a1, b1] = atY(i - 0.5);
        if (a1 !== undefined && b1 !== undefined) {
            [a2, b2] = atY(-i +0.5);
            if (pa1) {
                addEdgeLine(pa1 + x, a1 + x, y + i - 1);
                addEdgeLine(pb1 + x, b1 + x, y + i - 1);
                if (i > 1) {
                    addEdgeLine(pa2 + x, a2 + x, y - i + 1);
                    addEdgeLine(pb2 + x, b2 + x, y - i + 1);
                }
                pa2 = a2;
                pb2 = b2;       
            } else {
                pa2 = min(a1,a2);
                pb2 = max(b1,b2);
            }
            pa1 = a1;
            pb1 = b1;
        } else { 
            // add last row (top bottom)
            if (pa1) {
                 addEdgeLine(pa1 + x, pb1 + x, y + i - 1);
                 addEdgeLine(pa2 + x, pb2 + x, y - i + 1);   
            }
            scan = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
var tick = 0;
function renderLoop(time) {
    if (tick++ % 4 === 0) {
        time /= 4;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
        const h = Math.sin(time * 0.001) ** 2 * 34 + 10;
        const v = Math.sin(time * 0.00333) ** 2 * 35 + 10;
        scanEllipse(50, 50, h, v, time * 0.00077);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

}
```

```css
canvas { 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```